# How to get an object out of a collection in VBa

Tags: vba, excel

I used to have the following working code

```
Set result = DecodeJson(MyRequest.responseText)   
Dim keys() As String
keys = GetKeys(result.issues)
```

Now, my approach has changed and instead of having result being the object, I receive a Collection based upon [Array of class objects as class member in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309235/array-of-class-objects-as-class-member-in-vba)

```
Dim resultsFromQueries As Collection
Set resultsFromQueries = GetAllJSonObjects(searchString) ' this calls DecodeJson(MyRequest.responseText)  as per the code snippet above

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To resultsFromQueries.Count
    Dim keys() As String
    Dim item As Object
    Set item = resultsFromQueries.item(i + 1)  ' I guess it's not 0 based?
    keys = GetKeys(item.result.issues)   'KABOOM
```

The issue I have now is I keep getting the following exception

> Run time error '424':
>   Object required

Checking in the watch window, `item` shows as type `Variant/String` and has the value of `"[object Object]"`

Do I need to cast it?

Comment: If it's an object you are returning, you need to use `Set`: `Set item = resultsFromQueries.item(i + 1) `

Comment: Hi @Rory, sadly, the same issue persists (I've updated my post to show it)

Comment: It can't be a String if you used Set, so what object type is it now?

Comment: `resultsfromQueries` is a `Collection/Collection`. `Set item`... never gets executed due to the above error message @Rory

Comment: From what I can see, I think you will be getting an overflow error in your loop. try;  [For i = 0 To resultsFromQueries.Count - 1] and [Set item = resultsFromQueries.item(i)]

Comment: @Flephal, that doesn't address the issue sadly. Even so, I tried it and doing so only produces the error message `subscript out of range` on the `resultsFromQueries.item(i)`

Comment: @Rory, resultsfromQueries is a collection/collection. If I expand this in the watch window, I can see `Item 1` which is of type Variant/String

Comment: I still think it's probably an overflow error; Then try editing back to: [Set item = resultsFromQueries.item(i + 1)] with [For i = 0 To resultsFromQueries.Count - 1]. Also; have you tried creating a dummy collection to test the loop (use debug.print to see if it goes through the loop and what values are coming out)

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem just a few weeks ago, the problem was the following:

The collection was collected with the follwing code:`Collection.Add(OBJECT)`
This however leads to the addition of the value of the Object into the Collection and can be solved as simple as leaving the parathesis.`Collection.add OBJECT`
So my advice is to go into the `GetAllJSonObjects(searchString)` function and 
search for the addition process and make sure that it is without parethesis.
Like this the Collection will contain Objects and not variants and your code with item(i+1) should work properly.

Good luck!