# Multiple instances of an object/class

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a simple game in VBA excel that's like Rogue or Nethack. It takes place in a gui window. I've got an array to hold the playing field etc. and a class for the player, which has their coordinates stored and some subs to move around etc.

I then created an `NPC` class that moves around at random. I declared it the usual way, `Dim NPC as NPCclass` (inside the declarations) and then `Set NPC = New NPCclass` (inside a sub, which seems to be necessary but none of the tutorials mention that?) So far so good, the `NPC` is represented by an ASCII character and does what I want it to.

However, now I want to create more `NPCs` after intervals of a few turns. But I can't figure out how to do it. It seems like for every additional instance of my `NPC`, I have to do another `Dim NPCxyz as NPCclass`.

So I tried to generate a string, say `"npc_name"` that holds the name of the next `NPC` to be generated, as in `NPC1` or `NPC2` and so on. Unsurprisingly, if I then try `Dim npc_name As NPCclass` VBA doesn't understand that I want to create another instance of `NPCclass` with the string inside `npc_name` as its name. Instead it thinks I want to declare `npc_name` again, like when I said `Dim npc_name As String` earlier.

How can I create more NPCs that use the same class but move independently around the array/playfield? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something obvious because none of the tutorials I looked at went into this.

Comment: You are on the right track. The trick here is that as soon as you start thinking "Dynamically named variables" instead think "Arrays" or "Collections". You can have an array of your NPC objects or a collection of your NPC objects. [See here for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309235/array-of-class-objects-as-class-member-in-vba) Personally I would prefer a collection here since it's a little more versatile than an array, although an array would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an array of objects...

```
Dim NPC(1 to 20) as NPCclass

For i = 1 to 20
    Set NPC(i) = New NPCclass

    '... your object init ...
    NPC(i).SetSometing = 0
    NPC(i).DoSomething()
Next i
```

And if later on you want to increase the list you just need to do something like

```
ReDim Preserve NPC(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use **collections**:

```
Dim NPC as New NPCclass
Dim colNPC as New Collection

for i = 1 to 20
    colNPC.add New NPC
next
```